# SQLAlchemy no password supplied error

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is probably a silly error but I cannot seem to find a satisfying solution.

When running `db.create_all()`, I got the following error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied  None None
```

My database link is set as

```
'postgresql://localhost/db_name'
```

This worked fine on my Mac and Heroku, but is not OK on ubuntu (digitalocean).

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You probably just need to remove "localhost" from your connection string:

```
'postgresql:///db_name'
```

That tells psycopg2 to use Unix-domain sockets. Your default configuration will use "ident" so you'll be connecting as the user that runs the script. In the default configuration, "md5" only applies to TCP connections.

Comment: And how would you pass a different username in this way?

Comment: "Note: When ident is specified for a local (non-TCP/IP) connection, peer authentication (see Section 20.3.6) will be used instead." - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER - use "map" configuration to map os username to db username.

Comment: I am doing this on windows and I get the same error despite having the correct db string.

Comment: How do you know it's correct if it's not working?

Answer (score 50):

URL pattern should be:

```
postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/database_name
```

pip install psycopg2
the user should be postgres or any other user you have created and intend to use

similarly for mySql it would be:

```
mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/database_name
```

pip install mysql-python

Comment: I'm using peer authentication (so no password) and this isn't working for me, getting `no password supplied`. My connection string is `postgresql://user@localhost/db` where `user` is the linux user I'm running the code as.

Comment: I used this solution to solve my problem but in my case but I omitted the port from the URL: `postgresql://user:password@localhost/database_name`.

Comment: Thx @khwilo For users of AWS RDS, the default database_name is postgres

Comment: @omokehinde igbekoyi is there any way to hide the user and pass ?
I have a script which has command same like you but if somebody grep for the PostgreSQL process, it give a user id and password too. I dont want to expose that.

Comment: @punam you could set these in your env variable instead

Comment: I did still If I grep the process id it get displayed

Comment: It get displayed where? do you have a env file?

Answer (score 9):

On your Mac, PostgreSQL was set up for `trust` or `peer` authentication for connections from localhost.

On your Ubuntu box it's set up for `md5` authentication for connections from localhost.

You'll want to configure a password, or change the authentication mode. See [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), and the [Ubuntu guide for PostgreSQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL#fe_sendauth:_no_password_supplied) (there's a section about this error).

Answer (score 4):

Below worked for me. Your connection to your postgres database requires a password; thus, below is what you should write..

```
pg_user = "magicmike"
pg_pwd = "test123"
pg_port = "5432"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://{username}:{password}@localhost:{port}/foodversity_db".format(username=pg_user, password=pg_pwd, port=pg_port)
```

Comment: is there any way to hide the username and password ? I have a script which has command to connect PostgreSQL but if somebody grep ps -ef | postgresql , it give a user id and password too. I dont want to expose that

Answer (score -1):

First make sure that the database server is connected and then run the command again.Silly, but it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

For Remote Server

- remote server => `postgresql://<username>:<password>@<ipaddress>:<port>/<database>`

For Local in configuration use

- local db => `postgressql:///<database>`